# Fish population growth question: Can someone check my work and answers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reviewing for a math test this Tuesday and just want to make sure I'm doing things right. If someone could check my work that would be great.

Here's the question (work below):

[image]

Here's my work: [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @calculus it says the growth rate is 1.2% so isn't that 0.012?

Comment: @TheNewGuy Yes, that is what I meant. It was a typo.

Comment: @calculus I think part A is wrong though

Comment: @TheNewGuy Why do you think that ?

Comment: @calculus because I tried submitting it into my homework prep on webassign and it market it as wrong

Comment: @calculus actually I think I need to just put 13 and not the following zeroes, i'll try that. Edit: It worked!

Comment: It is a trick question you will get similar values if you use $e^{0.012 t}$ instead of the correct $e^{log(1.012)t}$ the correct answer for (b) is 13.799 instead of 13.804

Comment: also notice that you have to write $n(t)$ in millions, so you should not write out the zeros.

Comment: You cab follow the suggestion of John Joy. $f(t)=13\cdot e^{ln(1.012)\cdot t}$

Comment: Initially, I wouldn't even worry about $e$, but instead use a different base. Later, I would do some manipulations and change bases.$$13(1+\frac{1.2}{100})^t=13(1.012)^t = 13(e^{\ln 1.012})^t= 13e^{(\ln 1.012)t}$$

Comment: Thank you, can you help me set this one up properly?


The bat population in a certain Midwestern county was 260,000 in 2009, and the observed doubling time for the population is 28 years.
Find an exponential model $n(t) = n2 ^\frac{t}{a}$ for the population t years after 2009.


would this be correct? $$n(t) = 260,000*2^{\frac {t}{28}}$$

Also, if I were to put this in exponential model $n(t) = ne^{rt}$ how would I find the value of r? @calculus

Comment: @TheNewGuy Yes, it is correct, The equation is $2^{\frac{1}{28}}=e^r$ Taking the ln on both sides. $\ln\left( 2^{\frac{1}{28}}\right)=r$. Therefore $r\approx 0.024755$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only know that the growth rate is $1.2\%$, this is not equal to the exponential constant $r$. To find $r$ do the following:

After one year you know that there must be $n_0 \cdot 1.012$  fish, this has to be equal to $n_0 e^{r}$, thus $r = log(1.012)$

and you get: $n(t) = n_0 e^{log(1.012) t} = 13 \cdot e^{log(1.012) t}$

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. The function is given.

Answer (score -1):

Your answers are correct but your sketch is not. Because the population is growing exponentially then the derivative of the function will be positive (ie the line will curve upwards.) If you think about it the larger the population is the larger it will grow. Also I might add that the growth rate is 1.021 not 1.21. Apart from that its all good!

Comment: The growth rate is 0.021 not 1.021

Comment: The sketch is right. See here:                         https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5B13000000*e%5E%280.01*x%29%5D%2C0%3Cx%3C15

Comment: No the sketch isn't correct. I may being nitpicky but my point is that an exponential function will curve upwards as the top right picture depicts, not downwards as is sketched.